# Keydown in chrome does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Hello I been programming some scripts and I used Firefox to test them and they work great in FF. Now I tried in Chrome and the even keydown doesn't work in chrome. I tried keyup as well without luck. Here is the code that I am using:

```
 $("#inputAuthNum,#inputName").keydown(function (ev) {
        var key = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
        if (key === 13) {
            getData();
        }
    });
```

I tried to debug the script with firebug of Chrome but it doesn't call the event at all. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a working example of your issue with JSFiddle? **http://jsfiddle.net**

Comment: Well If I write a simple example in jsfiddle it does work in both browsers but still I have the same code in my .js but a bit more complex and it doesn't work: Here is the example that I tried and it worked http://jsfiddle.net/gmt9aqnf/

Comment: Then I'd say that the problem isn't with chrome, but with the rest of the code you're not showing us. Can you post the whole code?

Comment: I agree with @fgiobergia, you should post the entire code, because this snippet works good.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. The whole code is around 800 lines that is why I didn't post it. But since is working with Firefox and not with chrome, where would you start? how can I capture an event and debug it? I tried to set a breakpoint on the like of the event but It does not enter...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, just in case someone else has it.
Firefox's javascript allows to have optional parameters like:

```
function printForm (parameter='info') {
.....function
}
```

But chrome doesn't allow it, in any case we should remember that javascript allows to call a function without parameters so we could do something like:

```
    function printForm (parameter) {
         if (parameter == 'value') {
             alert ('value has been sent')
         } else {
             alert ('no parameter');
         }
    }
   printForm ('value');
   printForm(); //Will print 'No parameter'
```

I hope is useful.